# Determinant of a matrix with binomial entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am trying to prove that the determinant of the matrix with entries $a_{ij}=\binom{b-jn}{i}$ with $i,j=0,..., k$ where $b=kn+r$, with $r<k$, all positive integers, is given by:

- if $k$ is odd,$(-1)^{\frac{k+1}{2}} n^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}$;
- if $k$ is even $(-1)^{\frac{k}{2}} n^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}$

I have tried to use several formulas but I couldn't achieve it. Do you have any idea how to get it? The matrix is the following one:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 \binom{b}{0} &\binom{b-n}{0}& \binom{b-2n}{0}&\cdots & \binom{b-kn}{0}  \\ \binom{b}{1} & \binom{b-n}{1}& \binom{b-2n}{1}&\cdots & \binom{b-kn}{1}\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
 \binom{b}{k} & \binom{b-n}{k}& \binom{b-2n}{k}&\cdots & \binom{b-kn}{k}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Please list each attempt you made, given the several formulae you used.  Perhaps you made an error in one of them, that we can spot.

Comment: I have tried to condensate the matrix to the row echelon form, I have realised that the formula for the determinant is the above one after performing some steps and I have the conjecture that is the formula, but I can't find the way to prove it in general.

Comment: Please include those efforts in your post.  Start with the reduced row echelon form you came up with.  Or easier yet, post the matrix you tried to "condensate".  Please do not claim to have done what you fail to demonstrate in a question.

Comment: Did you try an inductive proof?

Comment: Yes, but the formulas I got are a nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

We start with the more general determinant
$$\det \begin{bmatrix} \binom{x_i}{j} \end{bmatrix}_{0 \leq i,j \leq k}$$
where the $x_i$ are general variables; later we will specialize to $x_i = b-in$.

We have
$$\binom{x}{j} = \frac{x^j}{j!} + (\mbox{lower degree terms in $x$}).$$
So the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} \binom{x_i}{j} \end{bmatrix}$ is related to the matrix  $\begin{bmatrix} \tfrac{x_i^j}{j!} \end{bmatrix}$ by multiplication by a lower triangular matrix with $1$'s on the diagonal, and we have
$$\det \begin{bmatrix} \binom{x_i}{j} \end{bmatrix} = 
\det \begin{bmatrix} \frac{x_i^j}{j!}  \end{bmatrix} = 
 \prod_{j=0}^k \frac{1}{j!} \cdot \det \begin{bmatrix} x_i^j \end{bmatrix} =
 \prod_{j=0}^k \frac{1}{j!} \cdot \prod_{0 \leq p<q \leq k} (x_q-x_p).$$
In the last step, we have used the formula for the Vandermonde determinant.

Now, putting $x_i = n-in$, we get
$$ \prod_{j=0}^k \frac{1}{j!} \prod_{0 \leq p<q \leq k} n(q-p) = n^{k(k+1)/2} \prod_{j=0}^k \frac{1}{j!} \prod_{0 \leq p<q \leq k} (q-p).$$

I'm going to be sloppy about signs. Up to getting the signs right, notice that
$$\prod_{0 \leq p<q \leq k} (q-p) = \prod_{q=0}^k q!$$
so the final product cancels the product of factorials and we win.

Comment: Nice trick, very well-done!